# MVC 4 unique field model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have been Googleing this and had no joy.

How do i add unique to a field in a code first approach in mvc4 .net

```
   public class Religion
    {
        public int ReligionId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

What would i need to add to description for this to work

Answer (score 1):

you may use remote validation 
review that link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx 
simple and fast